# Powerbook G4 Ubuntu Backlight Install Trouble

Tags: keyboard

I am following the keyboard backlight directions from this website

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCKnownIssues

I get through all the directions until I try the

```
make install
```

command.

I get this error:

```
Making install in .
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
/usr/bin/install -c -d /usr/local/etc
/usr/bin/install -c -d /var/lib/pbbuttons
/usr/bin/install -c -d /var/lib/ibam
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 --suffix=.old -b ./pbbuttonsd.cnf /usr/local     
/etc/pbbuttonsd.cnf
/usr/bin/install: cannot backup `/usr/local/etc/pbbuttonsd.cnf': Permission 
denied
make[2]: *** [install-data-local] Error 1
make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Any help would be great. I am running the compiler from the file itself by the way. So in my case its

```
user@????????:~/pbbuttonsd-0.8.1a$
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try running the `make install` command as `sudo make install`.

As per the

```
/usr/bin/install: cannot backup '/usr/local/etc/pbbuttonsd.cnf':
Permission denied
```

line, you (in the form of the `make install` command) are attempting to copy a file from `/usr/local/etc/`.

If I run `ls -l` (show permissions) on that directory in my computer, it returns `root` as the owner for the files in there, thus you would need root access (given via `sudo`) to change those files.